# WordPress wp_get_nav_menu_items - what is the first param for?

Tags: wordpress, menu

As far as I understand, to list all the menu items, we can use this `wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu, $args )`, and according to the doc:

> To get a list of menu items in WordPress you can use the function
>   wp_get_nav_menu_items(), this takes two parameters first being the
>   menu ID and second being extra parameters to customise the items.

But I don't understand, what is the **menu ID** about for the first param? What do I need it for? I just want to list all the menu items!

And I how can I get this $menu? Where do I get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly what it is - menu ID. But it doesn't have to be ID, it can be `name`, `slug` or `ID`. You can find your menus under `Appearance => Menus`. There you can find Menu Name which shows name of your menu which you can pass to `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` as first parameter. `value` in `<option>` in the dropdown of menus shows `ID` of each menu which you can also pass to `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` as first parameter. `slug` = result of call  of `sanitize_title()` with menu name passed as parameter and it can be also passed `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` as first parameter.

Comment: thanks but it still does not make sense. I just want the list of all my menu items. I have home, about, contact in the list for instance. So, 

`$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'contact' );
var_dump($menu_items);`

Then it just returns an empty array.

Comment: You need to pass `name`/`slug`/`ID` of menu, not an item. In [this](http://i.imgur.com/8zbAIqs.png) example, you'd need to pass `'dsfsd'` as first parameter to get data on these 4 menu items

Comment: @teelou `'dsfsd'` is a name of menu from picture example you can see if you click on this in my previous comment. You, of course, need to replace it with an actual name of your menu.

Comment: ok. I got it thanks. it is so confusing in WP. Still a bad program as before!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your problem. Cheers.